# Rabbitmq - AMQP GEM: Not able to publish messages on multiple exchanges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rabbitmq, amqp

In my ROR application, I have the requirement where I need to consume the messages from one exchange and then publish the same to another exhange after appending of some additional data to headers. So I have created an rake task to start the AMQP.

```
     EventMachine.run do
        $configurations = Config.new.config
       rmq_configurations = Config.new.rmq
        connection = AMQP.connect(rmq_configurations)
        $channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
        puts "AMQP listening"
        worker   = MessageHandler.new
        puts "Message handler started"
        worker.start
      end
```

And in the Message handler class, I have defined the exchanges as like below

```
     def initialize
         @ns_exchange = $configurations["ns_exchange"]
         @sc_exchange = $configurations["sc_exchange"]
         @ns_queue = $configurations["ns_queue"]
         @sc_queue = $configurations["sc_queue"]
       end


    def start
      @ns_x = $channel.direct(ns_exchange, :durable => true)
      @sc_x = $channel.direct(sc_exchange, :durable => true)
      @ns_queue   = $channel.queue(ns_queue, :auto_delete => true)
      @ns_queue.bind(@ns_x, :routing_key => "ipam").subscribe(&method(:handle_ns_message))
      message_headers = {"messageType" => "ipam/operations/ip/checkCanAllocateIP"}
      message_body = {"ipsToAllocate" => "1", "orgId" => "438c6cdd-aa2d-4f3c-bec3-aefb85d6fca5"}
      @ns_x.publish(message_body,  :routing_key => "ipam", :headers => message_headers, :mandatory => true)

      @sc_queue   = ch2.queue(sc_queue, :auto_delete => true)
      @sc_queue.bind(@sc_x, :routing_key => @sc_queue.name).subscribe(&method(:handle_sc_message))
     @sc_x.publish(message_body,  :routing_key => "ipam", :headers => message_headers, :mandatory => true)
     end
```

Publishing is working only if I have one exchange. Also I never want to close the connection since AMQP needs to run always to consume & produce the message

Answer (score 0):

Able to publish the messages once I created the separate channels for each exchanges